# VBA Search Criteria, If Match found, Copy and Paste 2 different sets of data into a new table

Tags: excel, vba, search, copy-paste

I have been stuck on this problem for a couple of weeks now and I am reaching out for help and guidance on what to do next and hopefully finally have a solution. Searching through this website provided a lot of great solutions but none that I can get working right.

Task:

Search through Columns A & B for the Search Criteria located in Column K3 and L4

If there is a Match, copy paste columns D-F and N3-P3 into a new table(K9-P9)

Visual Screenshot of what I am trying to do:

[image]

Current Code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim base_Position, reverse__BaseDirection As Range
Dim searchCol_AB, rangeUnion_Copy, rangeUnion_Paste As Range
Dim Cell As Object
Dim wsSyn As Worksheet

Set wsSyn = Sheets("Syn_Calc")

Set base_Position = wsSyn.Range("K3")
Set reverse__BaseDirection = wsSyn.Range("L4")

searchCol_AB = wsSyn.Range("A3:B100")
Set rangeUnion_Copy = Union(Cells(, 4), Cells(, 5), Cells(, 6))
Set rangeUnion_Paste = Union(Cells(, 11), Cells(, 12), Cells(, 13))


For Each Cell In searchCol_AB
   If Cell.Value = UCase(base_Position) And UCase(reverse__BaseDirection) Then

   rangeUnion_Copy.Copy rangeUnion_Paste.Address

  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Problem:

1. I am not sure that the solution I currently have will do what I want it to do. I think there may be a better option then using Ucase.
2. Immediate issue right now is that the code is stuck on an error" Object Required". I can't seem to see why this is happening. 
   [image]

**Note: I haven't included the code to copy data from N3:P3 yet since I can't get the first part working.**

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
April

Comment: To start you off, please add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module. Then, observe that *Dim base_Postion, reverse__BaseDirection As Range* the data type of base_Postion is *Variant* because it's unspecified. If you want it to be a range the line should read *Dim base_Postion As Range, reverse__BaseDirection As Range*. Having set `Option Explicit` VBA will point out to you that *base_Position* is an undeclared variable, because you mis-spelled the name in the Dim statement.

Comment: Thanks Variatus. I corrected the Spelling error and added Option Explicit. However, I am still getting the Object error but this time on "If Cell. Value" line. I updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: Please wait a little while. I shall post a fully commented copy of your code shortly.

Comment: Will Do. Thanks Variatus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the your own code, fully commented. Sorry, I didn't get as far as to check whether it could actually do what you want if it were corrected.

```
Sub CurrentCode()

    Dim wsSyn As Worksheet
'    Dim base_Postion, reverse__BaseDirection As Range
    Dim base_Position, reverse__BaseDirection As Range
    Dim searchCol_AB, rangeUnion_Copy, rangeUnion_Paste As Range
    Dim Cell As Object

    Set wsSyn = Sheets("Syn_Calc")
    ' Since base_Position is a variant the line below assigns a range to it.
    Set base_Position = wsSyn.Range("K3")
    ' reverse__BaseDirection is declared as a range.
    ' Therefore this cariable is assigned a range as well
    Set reverse__BaseDirection = wsSyn.Range("L4")

    ' ==================================================
        ' The above concept is probably wrong.
        ' If you wish to search for the values in K3 and L4
        ' you should have declared both variables as Strings or Variants
        ' and assigns the respective ranges' Values to them, such
        ' base_Position = wsSyn.Range("K3").Value
    ' ==================================================


    ' searchCol_AB is declared as a Variant and can therefore be assigned anything.
    ' If you wanted to assign a range to it, the Set statement would be required, like
    ' Set searchCol_AB = wsSyn.Range("A3:B100")
    ' since you omit the Set statement VBA will presume that you mean to
    ' assign the property of wsSyn.Range("A3:B100").
    ' Since you don't specify which property you mean, VBA will assign
    ' the default property which is Value.
    searchCol_AB = wsSyn.Range("A3:B100")

    ' ==================================================
        ' The above facts propbably don't fit your intentions.
        ' Since searchCol_AB is intended to be searched it should be a range.
        ' Therefore: Dim searchCol_AB As Range
        ' and Set searchCol_AB = wsSyn.Range("A3:B100")
    ' ==================================================

    ' rangeUnion_Copy is dimensioned as a Variant
    ' Yes, you can assign a range object to it but why not declare it as a Range?
    Set rangeUnion_Copy = Union(Cells(, 4), Cells(, 5), Cells(, 6))
    Set rangeUnion_Paste = Union(Cells(, 11), Cells(, 12), Cells(, 13))

    ' ==================================================
        ' Cells(, 4) misses the row number.
        ' VBA will correct the error and insert 1 instead.
        ' Therefore, Union(Cells(, 4), Cells(, 5), Cells(, 6))
        ' is equivalent to Union(Cells(1, 4), Cells(1, 5), Cells(1, 6))
        ' is equivalent to Range("D1:F1")

        ' Application.Union creates a range consisting of incontiguous cells
        ' like Union(Cells(1, 4), Cells(1, 6))
        ' Range("D1:F1") is just a normal range, not a Union.
        ' you might use Set rangeUnion_Copy = Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(1, 6))
        ' if you need to change thr rows in a loop that might look like
        ' Set rangeUnion_Copy = Range(Cells(R, 4), Cells(R, 6))
        ' where R is the For ... Next loop counter
    ' ==================================================


    ' your code fails on the next line because
    ' searchCol_AB holds the values of range wsSyn.Range("A3:B100"),
    ' not the range itself.
    For Each Cell In searchCol_AB
        ' ==================================================
            ' A range can have many cells.
            ' the smallest range has a single cell.
            ' Ergo, a cell is a range.
            ' True, a range is an object.
            ' By declaring Cell as an Object you are employing what
            ' is called "late binding", meaning VBA only finds out
            ' which kind of object (Range) it is when it is used.
            ' You might find late binding beyond the scope of your current
            ' knowledge and therefore declare a range as a range for the time being.
        ' ==================================================

        If Cell.Value = UCase(base_Position) And UCase(reverse__BaseDirection) Then
            ' base_Position is a variable of variant type to which a range was assigned.
            ' Therefore base_Position is a range object.
            ' UCase([Range object]) is impossible.
            ' Therefore VBA executes UCase([Range_object.Value])
            ' That gives the result you intend but in a way you didn't understand.
            ' Better to avoid the use of default properties.

        ' ==================================================
            ' If Cell.Value = UCase(base_Position) And UCase(reverse__BaseDirection) Then
            ' is a common logical error. The correct syntax is
            ' If Cell.Value = UCase(base_Position) And Cell.Value = UCase(reverse__BaseDirection) Then
            ' some programmers would add parentheses for better clarity, thus:-
            ' If (Cell.Value = UCase(base_Position)) And (Cell.Value = UCase(reverse__BaseDirection)) Then
            ' Note that each expressions is evaluated to True or False.
        ' ==================================================

            ' The Copy command requires specification of a Destination cell.
            ' Destination is either a single cell (better, since less prone to errors)
            ' or a range of equal size to the copied range.
            ' It can't be a string, such as rangeUnion_Paste.Address
            ' (The Address property always holds a String)
            rangeUnion_Copy.Copy rangeUnion_Paste.Address

        ' ==================================================
            ' The way you have set rangeUnion_Paste it is of equal size
            ' to rangeUnion_Copy. Therefore either of the following would work.
            ' rangeUnion_Copy.Copy Destination:= Range(rangeUnion_Paste.Address)
            ' rangeUnion_Copy.Copy Destination:= rangeUnion_Paste
            ' rangeUnion_Copy.Copy Destination:= rangeUnion_Paste.Cells(1)
        ' ==================================================

        End If
    Next Cell           ' better specify which "Next" is called
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing comments! This will propel my learning curve tremendously. Let me read through in detail and try this out. I will let you know Variatus. Thank you! :)

Comment: So good news is I am not getting any more errors. Bad news is that nothing is happening. Nothing gets copied or pasted. I tried to add breaks to catch where it is happening but it never "broke" so something else is going on. Based off your comments this is what I added.  [Picture of new Code](https://ibb.co/tzT3fdG)    I had to export the worksheet into it's own workbook to troubleshoot this. That is why you will see Syn_Calc1 and other small changes.

Comment: I will keep working at it. I can also share with you the spreadsheet if interested

Comment: @April Parker I think you have taken from this thread what there was to be taken. If it has improved your knowledge the question can't be the same anymore. I suggest you rephrase it in a new thread. Everybody here, incl myself, didn't see how to tackle the fact that we didn't understand your intention in the light of the many syntax errors in your code. Now that the syntax errors would be much fewer your intention should be expressed more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Cell.Value = UCase(base_Position) And UCase(reverse__BaseDirection) Then
```

The above syntax is wrong but you haven't supplied enough information to offer a solution, only suggestions.

```
'If the text in base_Position equals Cell.Value and the text in reverse__BaseDirection equals Cell.Value
'this is unlikely because Cell.Value probably shouldn't be equal to both
If Cell.Value = UCase(base_Position) And Cell.Value = UCase(reverse__BaseDirection) Then

'If the text in base_Position equals Cell.Value and the text in reverse__BaseDirection equals Cell.Offest(0, 1).Value
'this is likely because Cell.Value equal one and the cell next to it equals the other
If Cell.Value = UCase(base_Position) And Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = reverse__BaseDirection Then
```

It doesn't appear from your image that you need to UCase reverse__BaseDirection.

In any event, you can see how the And syntax handles more than a single comparison.

You should also Set searchCol_AB to the range object.

```
Set searchCol_AB = wsSyn.Range("A3:B100")
```

If the second solution is correct using Cell.Offest(0, 1).Value then you only need to look through column A. The Offset will look at column B.

```
Set searchCol_AB = wsSyn.Range("A3:A100")
```

Wind it all up for something like this (see comments).

```
Option Explicit

Sub basePositionPairs()

    'these only need to be strings, not range objects
    Dim base_Position As String, reverse__BaseDirection As String
    'you need to specify each one or they end up as default variants
    Dim searchCol_AB As Range, rangeUnion_Copy As Range, rangeUnion_Paste As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim wsSyn As Worksheet

    Set wsSyn = Worksheets("Syn_Calc")

    base_Position = UCase(wsSyn.Range("K3").Value)
    reverse__BaseDirection = wsSyn.Range("L4").Value

    'look through column A and Offset to look at column B
    searchCol_AB = wsSyn.Range("A3:A100")
    'these full columns will be used with Intersect later
    Set rangeUnion_Copy = wsSyn.Range("D:F")
    'Start the paste at K9 (only top-left is required)
    Set rangeUnion_Paste = wsSyn.Range("K9")


    For Each Cell In searchCol_AB
        If Cell.Value = base_Position And Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = reverse__BaseDirection Then

            'copy the intersection of the full columns and Cell's row
            Intersect(Cell.EntireRow, rangeUnion_Copy).Copy _
              Destination:=rangeUnion_Paste

            'second copy from N3:P3
            wsSyn.Range("N3:P3").Copy _
              Destination:=rangeUnion_Paste.Offset(0, 4)

            'advance rangeUnion_Paste down one row
            Set rangeUnion_Paste = rangeUnion_Paste.Offset(1, 0)

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I added your solutions but now I am receiving an "Object doesn't support this property or method" Run-time error 438 on the same line in the screenshot above. I am googling this now but wanted to let you know. And to clarify a "Match" would be when ColumnA = Base_Position AND Column B equals reverse_BaseDirection. So there needs to be two matches together in order to copy and paste. Hope that helps? I didn't offer other possible solutions, you are right. I have already tried so many. Next time I will post what i tried already.